# Using flashdata while posting same controller twice in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to submit a EDIT form which edits Users Academics Details,
These Details have unique id in DB and my Code in Short Looks like below :

```
class edit extends ci_controller
{

function user_academics($id = NULL)
    {
        if(isset($id) == FALSE)     //if link is ./edit/user_academics
        {
            $id = NULL;
            $link = site_url('profile');
            show_error("Invalid Page Request! <a href='$link' Go to Profile </a>");
        }

        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');        
        $data['fill'] = $this->edit_model->get_user_academics($id);

        if($user_id != $data['fill']['user_id'])    // check if logged in user is accessing his record or others
        {
             $link = site_url('profile');
            show_error("This is an Invalid Request ! <a href='$link'>Go to Profile </a>");
        }
        else // actual work starts here
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('ua_id',$id); // update_academics will get this data

            $this->load->view('edit/edit_3_view',$data);

        }
    }

 function update_academics()
    {
        $ua_id =  $this->session->flashdata('ua_id');   // flash data used here .
        if( !$ua_id )
        {
            show_error('Sorry, This request is not valid!');

        }
      $academics = array( 
            // All post values
        );

        $this->edit_model->update_user_academics($academics,$ua_id);
        //print_r($academics);
        redirect('profile');

    }

}
```

Now the problem is 
- If I open two different records to edit, then It will set only one Session Flash value.
- And No matter what I edit , the existing values of the last flash value gets updated.
Please Suggest me another way or Correct me if I am wrong in above code . Thanks

Comment: try storing the $id in an array. $data[] = $id; then pass the array or serialize the array and pass it in the flashdata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save that flashdata in array, like:

```
$myArr = array('value 1', 'value 1');
//set it
$this->session->set_flashdata('some_name', $myArr);
```

And in view:

```
$dataArrs = $this->session->flashdata('some_name');
//loop thru $dataArrs to show the flashdata
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I guess i will use id parameter again . and what you suggested .

Answer (score 0):

Flash data is simply like variable which is available only in next request, you can bypass this behavior by using two different keys with record id in it, so that when you use flash data for showing message you can access key with particular record id.